# add all theme options as an array or as a single options in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I developing a new wordpress theme with control panel has more than 100 option .. so I asked is it better to store all of this options as a one array and get it in a global variable and use it or store each option in a separate option?

What is the better for CPU usage and site speed . I noticed that the home page of the theme has a more than 120 queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should create an options array, and store it using a serialize function (which will give you a string instead of an array, so you can store it). Then, use unserialize to have your array again.

Use some cache for this options array.
Wordpress provides this function :

```
$result = wp_cache_get( 'my_result' );
if ( false === $result ) {
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
    wp_cache_set( 'my_result', $result );
} 
// Do something with $result;
```

Comment: thanks for your replay .. But what is the benefit of set the array of options in cache ?

Comment: If your options array is cached, you won't have to make a new query to get it. You're saving a query, and CPU. I guess it's stored in the RAM.

Comment: But get_option() function makes the query once and cache the result !!

Comment: No, the following user will trigger a new query.
With this code, you'll set the $result in the wordpress cache. So $result won't be false after the wp_cache_get, and you'll be able to use $result without triggering a new query.
Don't forget to install a persistant plugin, see the doc for more informations. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache

Comment: When I use get_option('home_url') it will make a query and store the value in cache then I use it again get_option('home_url') it will fetch value from cache first .. Is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old question, but I just wanted to add to the comments of the previous answer.

`get_option()` does indeed make a database query, then store the value in cache, to be used on subsequent calls. But that will happen only on the first call to `get_option()` for the current page load.
So when a new page loads, `get_option()` will again get the value from the database and save it to the cache.

But in the case where you want to update the option value in database, and then also use that new value on the same page, then `get_option()` will be retreiving the value from the cache (which is the old value before updating the option).

Thats why then you would need to update the cache.